# Is this samarskite producing Xe-135?

Tags: experimental-physics, radioactivity

I left a small sample of samarskite (a uranium bearing mineral) directly beside a radiation monitor for a few days as in the photo below.  I then removed the samarskite, left the radiation monitor in place and measured activity for a few days.  I was surprised by what I saw.  Immediately after removing the samarskite the monitor detected activity about four times the normal background.  Over the next few days an exponential decay curve was formed.  The monitor seemed to be detecting something with a half-life in the range of 10 hours as shown in the graph below.

I am wondering if the uranium in the sample is producing xenon-135 (or iodine-135) which is remaining inside the monitor and/or surroundings.

[image: Small rock near a radiation monitor]
[image]

Comment: Maybe [Radon 222](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_chain#Uranium_series). This has a half-life of 3.8 days, but I don't see why it couldn't be leaking out of the monitor with a half-life of 10 hours. Certainly radon is a much bigger source of radioactivity in uranium mines than fission products.

Comment: I tried a follow up experiment where I put the samarskite sample in a small sealed plastic jar for a few days and then removed the samarskite and  resealed and monitored the "empty" jar.  It started with an activity of about one and a half times background and dropped off with a half-life of about 8 hours though the data was pretty noisy.

Comment: What Peter said. The probability of fission is around a millionth that of simple alpha decay. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_fission#Spontaneous_fission_rates

Comment: Have you tried placing the monitor in a sealed container on it's own ?  After all, you want to eliminate the possibility the monitor is the source of the problem.  Also be careful if you are reusing a container that may have been contaminated before as this could be a source of problems too.

Comment: @peter Does the monitor have an inside, to trap  stuff?  You have the radon-222 leaking *out* of the monitor?

Comment: @DJohnM ... Or its surroundings.

Comment: @PeterShor Are you saying uranium produces more Radon-222 then Xe-135?

Comment: @M.Enns: from PM2Ring's reference, it produces around a million times as much.